# I don't know what is wrong with this code problem is syntax error foreign key on delete and on update

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, foreign-keys, key

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    stu_id CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    stu_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    stu_minit CHAR,
    stu_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE FGKMKJWEKJH
(
    stu_id CHAR(5),
    crs_id CHAR(8),
    sem_id CHAR(5),
    Grade CHAR(2),
    Mark DECIMAL(4, 2) CHECK (Mark BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00),

    CONSTRAINT fk_inv_product_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (stu_id) REFERENCES STUDENT(stu_id)
             ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT pkVW 
        PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, crs_id, sem_id)
);
```

Comment: Can you please post the **complete and accurate** error message(s) you're getting?? Also: which **version** of SQL Server is this for??

Comment: `stu_id` in the `FGKMKJWEKJH` table is part of the `primary key` and also you have the FK behavior set to `SET NULL` on delete.  The value of null will violate the `primary key` constraint, so that's invalid.  You'll need to remove the `SET NULL` behavior or remove that column from the `primary key` constraint... `PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, crs_id, sem_id)`.  `CASCADE` would be a valid FK constraint option, but not `SET NULL`.

Comment: If you actually *read* the error this generates it tells you *exactly* the issue `because one or more referencing columns are not nullable.`

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is `stu_id` is part of the `primary key` constraint of `FGKMKJWEKJH`, which means `stu_id` is required to be `NOT NULL`.

Here's one valid option.  Instead of `SET NULL`, use `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE FGKMKJWEKJH
(
    stu_id CHAR(5),
    crs_id CHAR(8),
    sem_id CHAR(5),
    Grade CHAR(2),
    Mark DECIMAL(4, 2) CHECK (Mark BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00),
    CONSTRAINT fk_inv_product_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (stu_id) REFERENCES STUDENT(stu_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT pkVW 
        PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, crs_id, sem_id)
);
```

and the fiddle:

[Fiddle showing the old and new behavior](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f74a1ec91b034b58ac116ae3e52cc2d)